# jquery attribute selection always returning false?

Tags: jquery, html

I'm messing around with inline attributes and using them to trigger events with jQuery, but I've come across an issue.

I am trying to trigger a console log (in chrome) when an element has the attribute `self-toggle="dropdown"`. But with my lack of knowledge I can't seem to get it to work.

My HTML (anchor tag to test):

```
<a href="#" self-toggle="dropdown">dropdown</a>
<a href="#">not dropdown</a>
```

My jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(this).on('click', function() {
        if($(this).attr('[self-toggle]') == "dropdown") {
            console.log('self-toggle: true');
        } else {
            console.log('self-toggle: false');
        };
    });
});
```

Why doesn't this work, [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ykkya5Lj/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://jsfiddle.net/ykkya5Lj/1/

You don't need [ and ] around the attribute name and also you weren't hooking up to the click of `a` elements. When you bind to `a` click, $(this) will be the link you clicked on.

```
   $('a').on('click', function() {
        if($(this).attr('self-toggle') == "dropdown") {
            console.log('self-toggle: true');
        } else {
            console.log('self-toggle: false');
        };
    });
```

Comment: You are allowed, that's what I'm doing here. But you weren't binding to the click of a, but instead binding to the click of the document. `$(this).on('click'` binds to the click of the document. So in your handler $(this) was referring to the document, which doesn't have the attribute. So you need to bind to the click of a element, so $(this) inside the handler refers to the a, from which you can get the attribute value.

Answer (score 0):

You need to just pass the attribute name to [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a').on('click', function() {
    if ($(this).attr('self-toggle') == "dropdown") {
      log('self-toggle: true');
    } else {
      log('self-toggle: false');
    };
  });
});

var $log = $('#log');

function log(message) {
  $('<p/>', {
    html: message
  }).prependTo($log)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" self-toggle="dropdown">dropdown</a>
<a href="#">not dropdown</a>

<div id="log"></div>
```